# Minimal Polynomial of $AB$ and $BA$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, minimal-polynomials

> Let $A,B$ be linear operators on a complex vector space $V$. Prove the following:
>
> (a) For any polynomial $p$ such that $p(AB)=0$, if $q(x)=x\cdot p(x)$, then $q(BA)=0$
>
> (b) Use part (a) to show that if $m_{AB}$ is the minimal polynomial of $AB$, then $m_{AB}=m_{BA}$ or $m_{AB}=x\cdot m_{BA}$.

I've proven part (a). For part (b), I think there should be a third possibility, $m_{BA}=x\cdot m_{AB}$. Is this correct?

Here's what I have:

$m_{AB}(AB)=0$, so by part (a), if $q(x)=x\cdot m_{AB}$, then $q(BA)=0$. So $m_{BA}|q\implies\exists \ g\in\mathbb{C}[x]$ s.t. $m_{BA}\cdot g=q=x\cdot m_{AB}$. Reversing the roles of $AB$ and $BA$ $\exists\tilde{g}\in\mathbb{C}[x]$ s.t. $m_{AB}\cdot\tilde{g}=x\cdot m_{BA}$.

Hence, \begin{cases}m_{BA}\cdot g=x\cdot m_{AB}\\ m_{AB}\cdot\tilde{g}=x\cdot m_{BA}\end{cases}. This implies $m_{AB}\cdot\tilde{g}g=x\cdot m_{BA}\cdot g=x^2\cdot m_{AB}$. So $\tilde{g}g=x^2$. Which means we have three cases:

(1) $g=\tilde{g}=x$,

(2) $g=x^2,\tilde{g}=1$, or

(3) $g=1,\tilde{g}=x^2$.

For case (1), $m_{BA}\cdot x=x\cdot m_{AB}\implies m_{AB}=m_{BA}$. For case (2) $m_{AB}=x\cdot m_{BA}$. For case (3), $m_{BA}=x\cdot m_{AB}$.

Comment: Of course, it's correct.